# Problem with multipart/form-data with Python and an API that uses requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a problem trying to upload a file via multipart/form-data. The problem is not with requests/toolbelt but the API I am working with (is an API that mainly uses requests for a particular platform called Mercado Libre, similar to Ebay).

I'm posting the relevant code:

The particular method of the API:

```
def post(self, path, body=None, params=None, extra_headers=None):
    params = params or {}
    headers = {'Accept': 'application/json', 'User-Agent':self.SDK_VERSION, 'Content-type':'application/json'}
    if extra_headers:
        headers.update(extra_headers)
    uri = self.make_path(path)
    if body:
        body = json.dumps(body)

    response = self._requests.post(uri, data=body, params=urlencode(params), headers=headers)
    return response
```

My code:

```
from requests_toolbelt import MultipartEncoder

encoder = MultipartEncoder(
    fields={
        'file': (
        'myfile.txt',
            open('/tmp/myfile.txt', 'rb'),
            'text/plain'
        )
    }
)

self.post(path='the-url-path', body=encoder, extra_headers={'Content-type': encoder.content_type})
```

Of course this wil gives an error because the method line: body = json.dumps(body):

> TypeError: Object of type 'MultipartEncoder' is not JSON serializable

What I am doing wrong or how I can fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: But the biggest problem is what JSON standard form is. `json.dumps` did not support bytes and `MultipartEncoder`. In fact you should ask API developer did it support upload a file. because sending file in json is different from in Multipart. I am sorry for providing you with an uncertain answer.

Comment: Yes, is supported they say... Is there a way to create a multipart/form-data using json?

Comment: yes, it can. But it seems you can not finish it by this module, or you should change your way to do that. My idea is to create a dict which follow rule  
 https://developers.mercadolibre.com/en_us/working-with-pictures  https://developers.mercadolibre.com/en_us/item-description-2#Uploading-item-description

Comment: And i think you can imitate `curl` and build your own script, because the module you are using is so short and incomplete

Comment: @kcorlidy yes, is how I do in the rest of the requests that does not need files upload, but I don't know how for files (or how to translate the curl example for requests).

Also, I've tested to add files param to the post method, but does not work and returns status 500. Talking with Mercado Libre developers is a waste of time, they always reply "we only reply problems with the API"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I just implemented the solution using pycurl as @kcorlidy suggested till developers of that API write the right way to do it with requests. So, I've added an alternative method to the API to upload multipart/form-data files (also a utility class to return response similar to requests):

```
def post_files(self, path, files, access_token):
    '''
        Método adicional para subir archivos dado que el método post()
        de esta api no permite la subida mediante requets, param files.
    '''
    headers = [
        'Accept:application/json',
        'User-Agent:{}'.format(self.SDK_VERSION),
        'Content-type:multipart/form-data'
    ] 
    url = os.path.join(self.make_path(path), '?access_token={}'.format(access_token))     

    curl = pycurl.Curl()
    data = BytesIO()
    header_data = BytesIO()

    curl.setopt(pycurl.URL, url) 
    curl.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, headers)
    for name, filename in files.items():
        curl.setopt(pycurl.HTTPPOST, [
            (name, (
                pycurl.FORM_FILE, filename
            )),
        ])
    #curl.setopt(pycurl.VERBOSE, 1)

    # Escribimos response y headers
    curl.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, data.write)
    curl.setopt(pycurl.HEADERFUNCTION, header_data.write)

    curl.perform()

    # Parseamos el header para obtener status message
    status_line = header_data.getvalue().decode('utf-8').splitlines()[0]
    match = re.match(r'HTTP\/\S*\s*\d+\s*(.*?)\s*$', status_line)
    if match:
        status_message = match.groups(1)[0]
    else:
        status_message = ''

    # Objeto response de curl 
    response = CurlResponse(
        response=data.getvalue(),
        status_code=curl.getinfo(pycurl.HTTP_CODE),
        status_message=status_message,
        url=url
    )

    curl.close()

    return response


class CurlResponse:
    '''
        Clase para armar la respuesta de pycurl y simular
        la respuesta del módulo requests
    '''
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(**kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return str('Response {} {}'.format(
            self.__dict__['status_code'],
            self.__dict__['status_message']
            )
        )

    def json(self):
        return json.loads(self.__dict__['response'])
```

Thanks @kcorlidy for the support!

Answer (score 0):

You need to operate with the file a little bit differently, by using the `with` keyword:

```
from requests_toolbelt import MultipartEncoder
with open('/tmp/myfile.txt', 'rb') as f:
    encoder = MultipartEncoder(
        fields={
            'file': (
            'myfile.txt',
                f,
                'text/plain'
            )
        }
    )

    self.post(path='the-url-path', body=encoder, extra_headers={'Content-type': encoder.content_type})
```

Answer (score 0):

I imitate the request from curl. But i did not have account in Mercado Libre, therefore i can not promise script is correct. However, if example on upload file document in right that this script should run successfully.

```
import requests

ACCESS_TOKEN = ""

url = "https://api.mercadolibre.com/pictures?access_token={}".format(ACCESS_TOKEN)


def post_file(s):
    path = "bg/background_hd_01.jpg"

    headers = {
                "Accept": "application/json"}
    files = {
        "file":("my.jpg",open(path,"rb"),"image/jpeg")
    }

    resp = s.post(url,files=files,headers=headers)
    data = resp.json()
    if data.get("id"):
        with open("log.txt","a+") as log:
            log.write("{}\n{}\n".format(path,resp.text))

with requests.Session() as s:
    post_file(s)
```

Comment: What you wrote is the same what the API does, except for the files parameter (which fails with status 500 if I add that).

Python API of Mercado Libre: https://github.com/mercadolibre/python-sdk

Comment: did you upload successfully if you use curl?

Comment: Just for testing, I've modified quickly the api post methos by using pycurl and works:

https://pastebin.com/iBpJwrC8